# ReadProcessMemory across module boundaries

Tags: java, winapi, jna, readprocessmemory

I'm using [`ReadProcessMemory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680553%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to read a process' memory. It seems like when I read across a module's end, the rest of the bytes are not read successfully. I'm also getting the following kernel error:

```
299: Only part of a ReadProcessMemory or WriteProcessMemory request was completed.
```

If I list all modules with `EnumProcessModules`, none of them contain the address I'm trying to read from but [`Cheat Engine`](https://www.cheatengine.org/) can show all the memory contents just fine. `Cheat Engine` says the module's size is `0xE000` and this is exactly the amount of bytes I can read before it stops and only places `0x00` bytes into the buffer which is incorrect and does not represent the actual memory contents.

[image]

Is the following code not suitable for reading across module boundaries (even if they are contiguous)?

```
static Memory getOutputMemory(Pointer openedProcess, long baseAddress, int length)
{
    val outputMemory = new Memory(length);
    val intByReference = new IntByReference();
    if (!MY_KERNEL_32.ReadProcessMemory(openedProcess, baseAddress,
            outputMemory, (int) outputMemory.size(), intByReference))
    {
        checkForKernelError();
    }

    return outputMemory;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, reading memory pages individually is how to do it e.g. like the following code:

```
public byte[] readBytes(long address, int length)
{
    val byteBuffer = allocate(length);

    var totalRemainingLength = length;
    var currentAddress = address;

    while (totalRemainingLength > 0)
    {
        val memoryBasicInformation = new MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION();
        val process = new HANDLE(processHandle);
        val pointer = new Pointer(currentAddress);
        val memoryPageQueryResult = KERNEL_32.VirtualQueryEx(process, pointer, memoryBasicInformation,
                new BaseTSD.SIZE_T(memoryBasicInformation.size()));
        if (memoryPageQueryResult.equals(new SIZE_T(0)))
        {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Memory not contiguous");
        }

        val memoryPageBaseAddress = nativeValue(memoryBasicInformation.baseAddress);
        val memoryPageSize = memoryBasicInformation.regionSize.longValue();
        val memoryPageEndAddress = memoryPageBaseAddress + memoryPageSize;

        val remainingMemoryPageBytes = memoryPageEndAddress - address;
        val currentLength = (int) min(totalRemainingLength, remainingMemoryPageBytes);
        val outputMemory = getOutputMemory(processHandle, currentAddress, currentLength);
        val byteArray = outputMemory.getByteArray(0, currentLength);
        byteBuffer.put(byteArray);

        currentAddress += currentLength;
        totalRemainingLength -= currentLength;
    }

    return byteBuffer.array();
}

static Memory getOutputMemory(Pointer openedProcess, long baseAddress, int length)
{
    val outputMemory = new Memory(length);
    val intByReference = new IntByReference();
    if (!MY_KERNEL_32.ReadProcessMemory(openedProcess, baseAddress,
            outputMemory, (int) outputMemory.size(), intByReference))
    {
        checkForKernelError();
    }

    return outputMemory;
}
```